# Mongodb find query optimization

Tags: javascript, mongodb, migration

I'm writing a `migration script` to update some fields of a collection, say `collection2`.
In our collections, we store Japanese dates with following format in each document:

```
"date" : { "era" : 4, "year" : 25, "month" : 11, "day" : 25 }// i.e `25-11-2014`
```

Now I'm looking for an easy way to get all the documents of the collection with `date > 1-10-2014` i.e

```
 date > { "era" : 4, "year" : 25, "month" : 10, "day" : 1 }
```

Code works well, but I'm feeling like it can be optimised but don't know how.

- iterating `collection1` using `forEach` and extracting its date
- check date `collection1.date >  1-10-2014`
- copy some document fields from `collection2` and update them

  ```
  db.col1.find({ name: x123 }).forEach(function(doc){
       if(hasValidDate(doc.date1)){
         db.col2.find({col1_id:doc._id}).forEach(function(doc2){
            var copyobj = {doc2.x1, doc2.x2, ...};
            db.col2.update({col1_id:doc._id}, copyobj);
         });
       }
  });

  function hasValidDate(date){
      return (date.era == 4 && date.year >= 26 &&
                           (date.month >= 10 && date.day >= 1))?true:false;   
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try including the actual date filtering within your **`find()`** query:

```
db.col1.find(
    { 
        "name": "x123",
        "date.era": 4,
        "date.year": { "$gte": 26 },
        "date.month": { "$gte": 10 },
        "date.day": { "$gte": 1 },
    }
).forEach(function(doc){
    var copyobj = { "$set": {"x1": "1", "x2": "3", ...} };
    db.col2.update({_id: doc._id}, copyobj);
});
```

Comment: Can you please also help me to optimize the code. Can it be done with single `forEach`?

Comment: @trex The above has a single `forEach`, I'm afraid I'm failing to understand your question, did you mean can't it be done without a `forEach()`?

Comment: @chridam-  No, Please have look at my code, I'm copying the data from collection2 and updating it in collection2 only. But in your case you're using `doc.x1` instead of `doc2.x1`.

Comment: @trex It's not making any sense, if you are copying data from the same source and updating it within the same source, what has changed then?

Comment: From old data I have to change only values of two fields other fields will remain same as is.  Ex. `doc2.x1 = "0"`  should become `doc2.x1 = "1" , etc`

Comment: @trex Oh, gotcha now. In that case you just need to explicitly create the update object. I will update my answer to reflect this.